# virtualenv and Pycharm: folders, and packages: how does it work?

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, virtualenv, coremltools

I created a project in Pycharm. Then I went down and typed pip install commands in to the terminal to install my required packages.
The strange thing is that my code only works, if the .py file is in the project root directory, and it does not work if it is in the 'venv' directory.
It don't know yet how exactly this works, and this looks to specific to just "google it".

Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want it in the `venv` folder? Your code is not supposed to go there, it is for your environment only.

Comment: Marko you provided to answer but I can't flag you as the resolver

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not supposed to go there, it is for your environment only. Move any source files to the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can read this docs to understand better what is virtualenv:
[what is virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#:%7E:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20a,part%20of%20your%20operating%20system.)

The virtualenv you built can use different python version other then you use in the Pycharm project.
Furthermore, virtualenv built with libs. when you did `pip install <lib>` you didn't install the lib in the virtualenv so it probably missing there.

Solution:

Activate virtualenv in terminal:

```
source path_to_virtualenv/bin/activate
```

install the lib again this time in the virtualenv:

```
pip install <lib>
```

this should help.